# How to use input() to specify a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use input() to call one of three possible lists (a, b, or c) and then run functions on that chosen list.

At one point I had this working, so not sure what I changed. I think it's an issue with the way it's declared.

```
a = ["1","2","3"]
b = ["4","5","6"]
c = ["7","8","9"]

choice = input("Choose a, b, or c")

print choice[0]

some_function(choice)
```

If input is `a` I want to get `"1"` as the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your lists in a `dict` instead of 3 separate variables.

```
choices = {
    'a': ["1","2","3"],
    'b': ["4","5","6"],
    'c': ["7","8","9"],
}

choice = input("Choose a, b, or c")

print(choices[choice])
```

Comment: `choices.get(choice, None)` would prevent exceptions for an invalid input (though its arguable wether exceptions should be ignored here or not)

Comment: Yeah, I deliberately avoided the issue of bad input here.

Comment: I figured but I leave that option as a comment just in case a future reading uses it :)

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dictionary. Here is how that would work.

dictionary = {"a": ["1", "2", "3"]}
choice = input("Choose a, b, or c: ")

print(dictionary[choice][0])

Dictionary uses a key and value. Your key here would be the string "a" (Keys are immutable) and value would be the corresponding array. Dictionary[key] gives you a value and Dictionary[key][0] is basically value[0]. So you are simply indexing the list.

You can use one dictionary for all declared lists.

dictionary = {"a": ["1", "2", "3"], "b": ["5", "6", "7"]} and onwards....

Plus they are more efficient than lists.